# Did Draupdi have the boon of turning virgin every morning or every year?

Tags: mahabharata

I have heard that Druapdi had the boon of turning virgin every day she took bath . Or Did she turn virgin every year ?

Comment: every year at end of living with one pandav, she used to take bath in agni (fire)